# Ransack - deep association sort link doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ransack

I am trying to sort column using Ransack, but with no luck.

Model Application

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

Model Order

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :executor_group, class_name: "Group"
end
```

Model Group

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, foreign_key: "executor_group_id"
end
```

Having those models, I am trying to sort like this (from application model/controller):

```
sort_link(search, :orders_executor_user_last_name, translation)
```

Controller search operation:

```
@search = Application.includes(:group).search(search_params)
@applications = @search.result.paginate(pagination_params)
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT `applications`.* FROM `applications` LEFT OUTER JOIN `orders` ON `orders`.`application_id` = `applications`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `groups` ON `groups`.`id` = `orders`.`executor_group_id` ORDER BY `groups`.`name` DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

So, I want to sort applications by executor group name, but executor group belongs to order, which belongs to application. 
Application -> Orders -> Executor group (Group).

Can anyone help me with this? Is it possible to sort by that deep relation?
Thanks.